# What does `bind.bind` mean? A strange way to use JavaScript bind

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book about writing JavaScript frameworks and found this code snippet. But I don't understand how it works, especially the `bind.bind` usage? Does anyone have a clue?

```
var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
var apply = bind.bind(bind.apply);
var fn = apply([].concat);
var a = [1, 2, 3], b = [4, [5, 6], 7];
fn(a, b);
//output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This takes me back to the days of solving and expanding equations.

**1 . First, lets expand the first apply function:**

```
var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
var apply = bind.bind(bind.apply);
var fn = apply([].concat);
```

Transforms to:

```
var apply = Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.bind.apply);
var fn = apply([].concat)
```

---

**2 . Secondly, we expand the fn function:**

```
var fn = Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.bind.apply)([].concat);
```

---

**3 . We now invent a js algebra rule and replace the `bind.bind...()` invocation with the call invocation.**

Actually we implement a replacement base on the notion that:

```
someFunction.bind(arg1)(arg2) <==> someFunction.call(arg1, arg2)
```

Therefore we can replace that and get:

```
var fn = Function.prototype.bind.call(Function.prototype.bind.apply, [].concat);
```

---

**4 . For our second js algebra rule we devise that:**

`someFn.bind.call(target, ...) <==> target.bind(...)`.

`someFn` is not important here because we don't call bind() on it. We invoke `call` on the `bind` - replacing the `this` that was `someFn` and therefor it is replaced with `target`.

Therefore we replace the `bind.call(target)` with the target.bind alternative

```
var fn = Function.prototype.bind.apply.bind([].concat)
```

---

**5 . If the last permutation was also doing invocation () we could have done a replace like:**

```
fn([1, 2], [3, 4]) <==> [].concat.apply([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

But we have only the bind without the invocation which we can replace and is equivalent to:

```
var fn = function (arg1, arg2) { 
    return [].concat.apply(arg1, arg2); 
}
// instead arg1 and arg2 we could use more accurate arguments logic also.
```

---

**Final Result**

```
var fn = Function.prototype.bind.apply.bind([].concat) 

// or

var fn = function (arg1, arg2) { 
    return [].concat.apply(arg1, arg2); 
}
```

The `fn` function takes the `concat` function and lets us us it in a functional style, without calling it from an object. Instead of `concat` binded to `this` of the caller, `fn` applies it on `arg1` as `this` and `arg2` as the other params to concatenation to `arg1`.

```
fn([1, 2], [3, [5, 6], 4])
// [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
```

Comment: so anyfunction.apply.call([].concat,[1,2],[3,[4,5],6])<==>[].concat.apply([1,2],[3,[4,5],6])<==>[1,2].concat(3,[4,5],6).Nice algebra!

Comment: Thanks. That is basically it, yes. The last transformation you mentioned although - `[].concat.apply(arg1, ...) <==>  arg1.concat(...)` is possible when the target has the same base function. For instance, the `argument` object that is like an array but does not have array functions. I relied on the fact that `bind`, `call` and `apply` exists on any function for those transformations.

Answer (score 12):

Because `Function.prototype.bind` is itself a function, it inherits itself as a method.

Typically, bind is called as an instance method of a particular function, but we can rebind it to `Function.prototype.apply` and return a higher-order function.

A less terse way of writing this would be:

```
function apply (fn) {
  return function (a, b) {
    return fn.apply(a, b)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We have to think a little about what `bind` actually does behind the scenes. To a rough approximation, it works like this:

```
function bind(fn, ...bound) {
    return (...other) => this.call(fn, ...bound, ...other);
}
```

(Remember that the lexical `this` refers to the function on which `bind` is called.) So taking

```
apply = bind.bind(bind.apply);
```

and manually expanding `bind` ourselves, we get:

```
apply = (...other) => bind.call(bind.apply, ...other);
```

We're only interested in passing a single argument, which is a function. Hopefully this also means that its `apply` property is the same as that of `bind`:

```
apply = (fn) => bind.call(fn.apply, fn);
```

But `bind` is (hopefully) itself also on `fn.apply`'s prototype, so we can simplify further to:

```
apply = (fn) => fn.apply.bind(fn);
```

We're now in a position to expand `bind` again:

```
apply = (fn) => (...other) => fn.apply.call(fn, ...other);
```

This time, we want two arguments, and the call to `call` can also be simplified:

```
apply = (fn) => (obj, args) => fn.apply(obj, args);
```

We're now in a position to invoke `apply` on `[].concat`:

```
fn = (obj, args) => [].concat.apply(obj, args);
```

`obj` needs to be an array for this to work, so this simplifies to:

```
fn = (obj, args) => obj.concat(...args);
```

And in the provided example we end up with

```
[1, 2, 3].concat(4, [5, 6], 7)
```

which returns the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

`bind()` method creates a new instance of the function to the value that was passed into `bind()`.

Here we are calling `Function.prototype.bind.apply(Function.prototype, [null].concat(arguments));` by breaking into separate executable code units.

Objective is to call `apply`; to pass the original function as the first param and then array of arguments.

This codes has different variables for each process involved to achieve bind with dynamic params.

```
var bind=Function.prototype.bind; 
  // the bind function is assigned to a var

var apply=bind.bind(bind.apply); 
  // a new function apply is created which is nothing but bind.apply

var fn=apply([].concat); 
  // the apply function is defined and now we have final function 
   that will concat array.
```

Last two lines are for executing the `fn` function by passing two parameters

`var a=[1,2,3],b=[4,[5,6],7];
fn(a,b);`

Answer (score 1):

### explanation via example

The technique below can be used to "**uncurry `this`**",
which means to turn a method into a function where it's `this` is provided as the first argument instead of `this` being implicit based on what object a method is called on.

```js
const map = new Map()
const set = Map.prototype.set
// ------------------------------
{ // STEP 0
  map.set(2, 'b') // normal method call
  // => depends on the `Map.prototype.set` not being corrupted to work
  // e.g. Map.prototype.set = undefined // breaks this line of code
}
// ------------------------------
{ // STEP 1
  // just as `map` in e.g. `map.set(...)`
  set.call(map, 2, 'b') // can pass `this` as param now (="uncurry this")
  // the first arg `map` becomes `this` of `set(...)`
  // => but depends on `Function.prototype.call` not being corrupted to work
  // e.g. Function.prototype.call = undefined // breaks this line of code
}
// ------------------------------
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
const call = Function.prototype.call
{ // STEP 2
  // just as `map` in e.g. `set.call(map, ...)`
  const set_call = call.bind(set) // think: "set.call(...)" in one function
  // the first arg `set` later becomes `this` of `set_call(...)`
  // to make `set.call` a **"single set_call function"**
  // => is the same as step 1, but we just use `bind`
  set_call(map, 2, 'b') // can pass `this` as a param now
  // => almost perfect, but every time we want to make another
  //    uncurried function e.g. `xyz_call(...)`
  //    instead of `xyz.call(...)
  //    we need to call `call.bind` again, which depends on prototypes
  // e.g. Function.prototype.bind = undefined
  // => breaks our "uncurried function making technique"
}
// ------------------------------
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind
const bind = Function.prototype.bind
{ // STEP 3
  // just as `set` in e.g. `call.bind(set)` to get `set_call`
  const call_bind = bind.bind(call) // corrupt prototype has no effect later
  // the first arg `call` later becomes `this` of `call_bind(...)`
  // to make `call.bind` a **"single call_bind function"**
  // =>
  // we make a "custom bound `bind`" with the first argument of `bind`
  // already set to `call`, hence `bind.bind(call)` => `call_bind`
  // => a `bind` where the "bind's `this`" is `call`
  // => as in `call.bind(...)` ... :-) yay!
  // ----------------------------------------
  // One more time (with different words):
  // This is basically the same as in step 2:
  // But instead of calling `call.bind(...) immediately on something
  // we bind `call` as the `this` for a function arg we provide later
  // so instead of `call.bind(set)` to make `set_call`,
  // we now can use our single helper function `call_bind(...)`
  const set_call = call_bind(set)
  set_call(map, 2, 'b')
}

// It might read funky :-), but it works in the exact same way:
// 1. While the former turned `set.call(...)` into a single function
// 2. The latter turns `call.bind(...)` into a single function
// =>
// `set_call` allows to "uncurry" `map.set`
// and we can now do `set_call(map,...)`
//
// `call_bind` allows to "uncurry" `call.bind`
// and we can now do `set_call = call_bind(set)`

// ------------------------------
// SUMMARY:

// So we went from
/*0.*/map.set(2, 'b')
// to 
/*2.*/set.call(map, 2, 'b')
// to
/*3.*/call.bind(set)(map, 2, 'b')
// to
/*4.*/bind.bind(call)(set)(map, 2, 'b')

// No prototype corruption will break anything now,
// because we have direct references to all functions
// and never have to call methods again
// which depend on prototypes not being broken.

// All we need to do once initially is:
{
  const { set } = Map.prototype.set
  const { bind, call } = Object.prototype
  const call_bind = bind.bind(call)
  // basically `call_bind` (a.k.a `uncurryThis`) is a single
  // uncorruptable function to create
  // as many uncurried functions later as we like :-)
  const map = new Map()
  // and now instead of
  map.set(2, 'b')
  // we can do without prototype dependent method calls
  const set_call = call_bind(set)
  set_call(map, 2, 'b')
}
// `set` and `map` and `set_call` and `call_bind` will always work
// no matter if prototypes change later or not.
// they do not depend on the prototypes anymore
```

For an even deeper dive, i can recommend:
http://web.archive.org/web/20160805225710/http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=conventions:safe_meta_programming